# How to get a scalar result from @NamedStoredProcedureQuery?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, stored-functions

If have a stored function that does stuff inside the database and returns a scalar (say, a generated key). I have defined it as a NamedStoredProcedureQuery:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name="do_something", 
                           procedureName = "dbo.do_something", 
                           parameters = {
                                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class, name = "param")
                                        }
)
```

I call the function using the entity manager:

```
Query doSomethingQuery = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("do_something");
doSomething.setParameter("param", 1);
Object result = doSomething.getSingleResult();
```

The stored function is called  but it seems my JPA provider, Hibernate, is not aware that it should expect a result to be returned. The generated SQL looks like this:

```
12:10:34,960  INFO SchemaCreatorImpl:489 - HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@30135202'
Hibernate: 
    {call dbo.do_something(?,?,?,?)}
12:10:35,251 TRACE BasicBinder:95 - binding parameter [param] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```

Now the problem is quite obvious. The call statement does not supply a bind-variable for the return value. IMHO it should be `{? = call dbo.do_something(?)}`.

I have tried adding `returnsResultSet=true` to the NamedStoredProcedureQuery but Hibernate 5.2.10.Final doesn't seems to have that implemented - even though Hibernate claim to be JPA 2.1 compatible. Another attempt was to add `resultClass = Integer.class` but that failed, too. It seems the resultClass has to be an entity. It will not work for a scalar.

Comment: in which way the sp returns the scalar value? output param, SELECT @R or RETURN @R?

Comment: It uses RETURN @R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"The stored procedure/function must return a resultset as the first out-parameter to be able to work with Hibernate"*

See [**16.2.2. Using stored procedures for querying**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) for reference

try to use

```
SELECT @R
```

instead of

```
RETURN @R
```

You can also try to add the SELECT before the RETURN (for your existing code)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the section in the documentation. I guess it is the right answer but I am afraid I can't change the signature of the procedure since it is alas used by legacy code. I probably will have to work with a wrapper.
I will file a CR so this feature can be added to Hibernate.

Comment: just add SELECT before the RETURN, this should work with existing code